# MySQL INSERT two fields only

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table with quite a few columns. The total number of columns is not yet specified, and will change on a regular basis.

In my insert query, I only need to put two values into the table. All other values will be ' '. is there a way to only specify the first fields, without having to include '','','',''...? Please see below for example:

I would like to have this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('','$id')");
```

Rather than this:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES('','$id','','','','','',''......and on and on...)");
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: do you know the 2 specific column names?

Comment: if yes try the second form in this link http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, specify the column names after the table name:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('','$id')
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd prefer

```
INSERT INTO table SET columnA = 'valueA', columnB = 'valueB'
```

Comment: Thanks Peter! I really like this one as it allows the following:
Table target: ID (PK), name (varchar)
INSERT INTO target set name = (SELECT name FROM source);

as this will insert many rows!

Answer (score 6):

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Answer (score 3):

Just define the fields you will insert,

eg:

```
INSERT INTO table (fieldA, fieldB) VALUES('','$id')
```

the missing fields will have the default value for that field